# project structure in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, project-structure

I have created a project in python and i want to put all the files in a standard format inside a folder ie I want to know the standard project structure of python.

My project contains following files:

```
(1) main.py 
(2) source_code1.py
(3) source_code2.py
(4) setup.py
(5) phpfile1.php
(6) phpfile2.php
(7) image1.png
(8) image2.png
(9) README.txt
(10) CHANGES.txt
(11) LICENSE.txt
(12) test1.py
(13) test2.py
```

Can anyone tell me, which file to put in which folder ?

NOTE: I have read almost all the related questions of project structure in python but not found where to put image files and other code files ends with different extension like .php , .html etc

Is there any standard way of project structuring in python ?

Answer (score 1):

- Make a new folder with your project name.
- Put setup.py , README.xt LICENSE.txt and CHANGES.txt there
- Inside it make a folder with the name of the app, keep main.py source-code1.py, source_code2.py in it.
- Another Images folder - Put image1.png and image2.png there
- Another folder Test for the test1.py and test2.py
- Another folder scripts and keep .php files there

Hope it helps

Comment: Is there any standard way for this? @user8477766

Comment: This is the standard way only.

Comment: any reference ? @user8477766